# Use terraform to create an instance in a specfic openstack network subnet

Tags: openstack, terraform

I want to create my openstack terraform instance in a specific existing (i.e. not created by terraform) subnet of a network.  I can create the port in the subnet and assign it to the instance - however I need to know the subnet *UUID* when I create the port.

How can I obtain the subnet *UUID* through terraform ?  I see I can import a subnet into the state file with 'import' but I still need to know the *UUID*.

I can obtain the network details with data.openstack_networking_network_v2.  Is there anyway to obtain a data.openstack_networking_subnet_v2 query?

```
resource "openstack_networking_port_v2" "m1ck_small_Chris_Subnet" {
    name = "m1ck_small_Chris_subnet"
    network_id = "${data.openstack_networking_network_v2.network_1.id}"
    admin_state_up = "true"
    fixed_ip {
        subnet_id = "c58354a4-4cb1-4863-9fce-fad5cd76b19b"
    }
}
```

How can terraform determine the subnet_id of an existing subnet?

Something like

```
data "openstack_networking_subnet_v2" "subnet1" {
    name = "subnet_name"
    network_id = "network_id"
}
```

Comment: If you *are* creating the subnet in TF, you can add a line like `uuid = openstack_networking_subnet_v2.SUBNET_ID.network_id` to the `network` block in the instance definition (which [isn't documented](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_v2) anywhere I've seen).  Note that the SUBNET_ID is the Terraform ID you specify in your subnet resource definition, not a UUID.

Answer (score 1):

I received word back from Terraform/Openstack that this is not supported at this time.

I plan to make use of the native nova/openstack cli to get this detail and have them available as variables to the terraform script.